# Ruby version and project not matching

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler, rbenv

When I run, `bundle` I see the following:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified
2.4.0.pre.dev
```

my Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.0-dev'
gem 'sinatra', :github => 'sinatra/sinatra'
```

This is my `gem env`:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.0 (2017-07-31 patchlevel -1) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/johndoe/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/bin
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/libexec
     - /Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/johndoe/google-cloud-sdk/bin
     - /Users/johndoe/Library/Python/2.7/bin
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

When I type `rbenv verions` this is what I see:

```
system
  2.0.0-p247
  2.3.1
* 2.4.0-dev (set by /Users/johndoe/code/projects/blog-server/.ruby-version)
```

With Rbenv I am specifying the ruby version I want, and I am matching this in my project's Gemfile. However, whenever I run `bundle` or `bundle exec gem uninstall sinatra` I see the above error message about my ruby version and my gemfile ruby version not matching. I also see that my Ruby version is 2.5.0, and I have no idea how that got set. Can someone help me resolve this error?

```
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified
2.4.0.pre.dev
```

In my bash profile, I have:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
....
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

In short, I just want the shell that runs my ruby process for my blog project to use ruby version `2.4.0-dev`, and I am struggling to see understand what's blocking me and how to resolve it.

UPDATE:

I also noticed something odd. My bundler version continues to point to ruby `2.5.0p-1`.

````
## Environment


Bundler   1.15.3
Rubygems  2.6.12
Ruby      2.5.0p-1 (2017-07-31 revision 59454) [x86_64-darwin16]
Git       2.11.0
Platform  x86_64-darwin-16
OpenSSL   OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.0-dev'
gem 'sinatra', '2.0.0'
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
<No /Users/johndoe/code/projects/blog-server/Gemfile.lock found>
````

Comment: There are a couple of ideas in [this issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260) in the bundler repo, have you gone through that one yet? Of particular note, the last post mentioned he needed to run `rbenv rehash` (only of note because I see you're using rbenv)

Comment: @SimpleLime I am familiar with that thread and nothing has worked for me. Every time I uninstall bundler and reinstall it, its Ruby version continues to be `Ruby 2.5.0p-1`.

Answer (score 0):

In a project folder run:

`rbenv local 2.4.0-dev`

It should do the trick. You just need to specify *local* ruby version for this particular project. And your global version is set to `2.5.0`

Comment: This did not work. I am still running into the same problem `Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0.pre.dev`. It seems that every time I run bundler, bundler runs with the ruby version, `2.5.0` vs the one I want 2.4.0.pre.dev.

Comment: @robertjewell Interesting. Ok, could you please post an output from `rbenv local` and `rbenv global` ?

Answer (score -3):

The best option here, I think, is to install Ruby Version Manager (rvm).

RVM helps every ruby developer by doing exactly what you need; manage ruby version automatically as you need.

Here's the link,  hope it helps;

https://rvm.io/

Cheers